# Подключение Mongo DB через mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Подключаю mongo. Выводит ошибки. Не могу понять их значимость и что править???Помогите, подскажите, пожалуйста.

const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
....

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:5000/danart", { useNewUrlParser: true });
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);

Ошибки вот такие в терминале выводит:

[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index index.js`
Server has been started on 5000         //показывает что сервер подключен, а вот дальше.....????? 
(node:5816) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: #
(node:5816) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a prom
ise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5816) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-z
ero exit code.

Comment: И что, после этого программа завершает работу?

Comment: MongoError: Authentication failed.
Пишет такую ошибку. Как ее решить?

Comment: Чтобы ее решить, нужно авторизироваться в БД. При подключении, в опциях укажите авторизационные данные http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/MongoClient.html#.connect

Comment: благодарю!Все чудесно